# Sorting data by two conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON object and I'm trying to sort it by both time and username alphabetically:

Sample data:

```
   const obj = [ {"timestamp": 1487184625, "user": "Eric", "action": "navigate"},
    {"timestamp": 1487184655, "user": "Bill", "action": "browse"},
    {"timestamp": 1487184685, "user": "Eric", "action": "key press"},
    {"timestamp": 1487184715, "user": "John", "action": "idle"},
    {"timestamp": 1487184755, "user": "Tran", "action": "search"},
    {"timestamp": 1487098049, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"},
    {"timestamp": 1487098079, "user": "Eric", "action": "click"},
    {"timestamp": 1487098109, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"},
    {"timestamp": 1487098139, "user": "Bill", "action": "navigate"},
    {"timestamp": 1487184625, "user": "Eric", "action": "navigate"},
    {"timestamp": 1487184655, "user": "Bill", "action": "browse"},
    {"timestamp": 1487184685, "user": "Eric", "action": "key press"},
    {"timestamp": 1487184715, "user": "John", "action": "idle"},
    {"timestamp": 1487184755, "user": "Tran", "action": "search"},
    {"timestamp": 1487098049, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"},
    {"timestamp": 1487098079, "user": "Eric", "action": "click"},
    {"timestamp": 1487098109, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"},
    {"timestamp": 1487098139, "user": "Bill", "action": "navigate"}]
```

I've tried something like this:

```
console.log(obj.sort((a,b) => {
  // if(a.user.localeCompare(b.user)){
  //   return 1
  // }
  // if(!a.user.localeCompare(b.user)){
  //   return -1
  // }
    if(a.timestamp > b.timestamp){
      return -1
    }
    if(a.timestamp < b.timestamp){
      return 1
    }
}))
```

But I can't seem to get it working. I'd like to avoid using Lodash as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: which one takes precedents, go by time first, then if it's the same time order by name next?

Comment: I'd like to order by name first and then time, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you want an ascending or descending sort for names/timestamps?

Comment: Ascending would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the result of `localeCompare` on the property `user`, if it is either `-1` or `1` then return that result. Otherwise (result is `0`), return the comparaison of `timestamp`:

```
obj.sort((a,b) => {
    var userComparaison = a.user.localeCompare(b.user);
    if(userComparaison) {                                 // userComparaison is either -1 or 1 (both are thruthy values)
        return userComparaison;                           // return userComparaison as the sorting criteria
    } else {                                              // otherwise (userComparaison is 0 which is falsy)
        return b.timestamp - a.timestamp;                 // compare by timestamp
    }
}
```

Which can be even shorter using a logical `||`:

```
obj.sort((a,b) => {
    return a.user.localeCompare(b.user) || b.timestamp - a.timestamp;
}
```

if `localeCompare` returned a truthy value (**i.e.** `-1` or `1`), then that truthy value will be returned and the rest of `||` will be ignored. If it returned a falsy value (**i.e.** `0`) then the value of the other operand of `||` will be returned (which is sorting by `timestamp`)

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved with a single sort function line:

```
 var results = obj.sort((a, b) => {
   return a.user.localeCompare(b.user) || b.timestamp - a.timestamp
 })
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t7hkp301/6/)

This works because `||` will only consider the second component if the `localeCompare` is zero.

---

I also want to point out that `||` is not only making the checking of the statement concise, it also allows you to chain further checks in your sorting requirement. For example, let's say you also want to sort by a third option (say action). You can by simply adding another `||`, and checking further.

Comment: Why not `a.user === b.user` `<---` faster!

Comment: @Ele Because you want to return the sort order value (negative/zero/positive) which `localeCompare` does and equality doesn't

Comment: I know, but it's faster a common comparison to make the decision, good approach btw.

Comment: So given your answer, If the list contains predominantly different names, then your method will actually be slower, because it is doing both an equality check and localeCompare. I prefer the `||` because of readability, and making it easy to add further chained checks if needed.

Answer (score 2):

This alternative compares the usernames first **(faster than a precipitated localeCompare execution)**, if they are equal then a common comparison between integers is executed.

```js
const obj = [{    "timestamp": 1487184625,    "user": "Eric",    "action": "navigate"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487184655,    "user": "Bill",    "action": "browse"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487184685,    "user": "Eric",    "action": "key press"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487184715,    "user": "John",    "action": "idle"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487184755,    "user": "Tran",    "action": "search"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487098049,    "user": "Tran",    "action": "click"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487098079,    "user": "Eric",    "action": "click"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487098109,    "user": "Tran",    "action": "click"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487098139,    "user": "Bill",    "action": "navigate"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487184625,    "user": "Eric",    "action": "navigate"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487184655,    "user": "Bill",    "action": "browse"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487184685,    "user": "Eric",    "action": "key press"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487184715,    "user": "John",    "action": "idle"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487184755,    "user": "Tran",    "action": "search"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487098049,    "user": "Tran",    "action": "click"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487098079,    "user": "Eric",    "action": "click"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487098109,    "user": "Tran",    "action": "click"  },  {    "timestamp": 1487098139,    "user": "Bill",    "action": "navigate"  }];

const sorted = obj.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.user === b.user) return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
  return a.user.localeCompare(b.user);
})

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(a.timestamp === b.timestamp){
    // compare usernames
    if ( a.username > b.username){
        return 1
    } 
    // etc
}
```

You are nearly there, you just need to add one more condition case as above. If times are the same, you then get the opportunity to sort by a secondary dimension ( or visa versa)