# Sort multiple array key's in ascending and descending order, string with number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of JavaScript objects:

This is not a duplicate question.
Because, I have an array of objects that has 2 keys (`key`, `count`).
I wanted to sort, `key` in ascending( which is *string*) AND `value` in descending(which is *number*) order.

```
 var array = [
  {"count":7,"key":"a"},
  {"count":10,"key":"b"},
  {"count":5,"key":"c"},
  {"count":10,"key":"a"},
  {"count":3,"key":"d"}
];
```

Desired Output:

```
     var array = [
      {"count":10,"key":"a"},
      {"count":10,"key":"b"},
      {"count":7,"key":"a"},
      {"count":5,"key":"c"},
      {"count":3,"key":"d"}
    ];
```

```js
var array = [{"count":7,"key":"a"},{"count":10,"key":"b"},{"count":5,"key":"c"},{"count":10,"key":"a"},{"count":3,"key":"d"}];

console.log(array.sort((a, b) => (b.count - a.count)));
```

`key` sort as **ascending**

`count` sort as **descending**

I have used `array.sort((a, b) => (b.count - a.count))` method for sorting count. but, Can't figure out how to sort both the keys of object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting data by two conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742914/sorting-data-by-two-conditions)

Comment: No, Its not a duplicate

Comment: By the answer you marked as correct, it is exactly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```js
var array = [{"count":7,"key":"a"},{"count":10,"key":"b"},{"count":5,"key":"c"},{"count":10,"key":"a"},{"count":3,"key":"d"}];

console.log(array.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.count === b.count) return a.key.localeCompare(b.key);
  return b.count - a.count;
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use logical `||` *operator* in combination with `localeCompare` function.

`||` operator will only consider the second component if the `b.count - a.count` result is *zero*.

```js
var array = [{"count":7,"key":"a"},{"count":10,"key":"b"},{"count":5,"key":"c"},{"count":10,"key":"a"},{"count":3,"key":"d"}];

console.log(array.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count || a.key.localeCompare(b.key)));
```